# How to force Android application to use either 32bit or 64 bit libraries

Tags: android, abi

On a Android device with 64bit ARM, would have two variants of many libraries, 32bit and 64 bit, and their performance could be different. I want to know if there is a way to force the application to use either 32bit or 64bit libraries.

Comment: `without native code to run in a specific mode.`? `32 bit and 64 bit driver libraries with` What are you talking about?

Comment: edited question, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ABI can be specified when the apk is installed.

`adb install --abi <path to apk>`

In case ARM device,

To run in 32 bit mode install using,

`adb install --abi armeabi-v7a <path to apk>`

To run in 64 bit mode install using,

`adb install --abi arm64-v8a <path to apk>`

Comment: Great answer, but what if I have to push it as a system app in a rooted device?

Answer (score 11):

1. If your apk is written in pure java (without jni), on 64-bit-primiary/32-bit-secondary Android OS, your app will always run in 64 bit mode by default, but if you want your app to run in 32 bit mode, you can create a dummy `*.so` file and put it under `<your apk name>/libs/armeabi/` to force AndroidRuntime to create a 32 bit VM for your app
2. If some function of your apk is written in jni (there's any `*.so` file in `<your apk name>/libs/` folder), you can use following command to make it run in 64 or 32 bit VM：

   - To run in 32 bit mode, because only 32 bit native libs will be installed

   `adb shell install --abi armeabi-v7a <path to your apk>`

   - To run in 64 bit mode, because only 64 bit native libs will be installed

   `adb shell install --abi arm64-v8a <path to your apk>`

Comment: How is this different from @Kanna's answer?

Comment: @VC.One The difference is I provided a way to force an pure java apk run in 32bit or 64bit mode.

Comment: @VC.One, this answer is far more indeep. And it answers a question how to force 32bit for customers of your apps, not only on your dev setup.

Answer (score 1):

https://source.android.com/source/64-bit-builds.html

Try this in you `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32 // or 64
```

Comment: I guess the question is not clear yet. If I have android application using lets say GLES api. System will have both 32bit and 64 bit libraries. And my application is in pure java. How can I run my application such that it uses 32 bit libraries? I guess by default it would pickup preferred abi. Sorry if I'm not making much sense, I'm not very familiar with Android.