# How to mix 32 and 64-bit .so files in an app

Tags: java, android, linux, android-ndk, ndk-build

First，I know that in an app does not allow mixed use of different architectures of the .so file（Part only uses 32, the other part only uses 64）

So,I tried to Open a new process to dynamically load 64 and 32-bit so files，but `System.load（）`throw the error and app crashed! How to solve this problem through multiple processes? Or is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Details about error would help a lot.

Comment: That's a cool idea! But what kind of child process do you want to start? A service? I don't think this could work, because the system decides whether to turn on 32-bit mode based on analysis of your APK, and the JVM is setup accordingly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31879900/192373: the **pm** can force the ABI while installing the app.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks! I agree with you, a child process(Activity) can not solve this problem。 [stackoverflow.com/a/31879900/192373] is not working, because I want part of the function uses 32-bit .so, and part of the function uses 64-bit .so，in the same app.

Comment: @AlexCohn Do you have any other ideas? Master

Comment: You can embed an executable binary in assets, unpack it to disk (with the so files) and launch with `System.exec()` or from native if you prefer. But I don't know if this will solve the mixed bitness problem - I have never tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did try. On the face of it, this works: use **armeabi** shared libs 'in the usual way', and run a **arm64-v8a** executable from Java with Runtime.exec() or from C with [system()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

You can put the executable in assets and unpack it manually, or you can [cheat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099666/192373) and rename it so that it starts with `lib` and ends with `.so`; now you can put this file in the **[jniLibs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38625690/192373)/armeabi** directory.

The opposite way works, too: launch 32-bit executable (don't forget `-fPIE`) from 64-bit app.

Make sure that the library search paths do not clash.

Comment: That's a cool idea!!!  My project is not similar to the video transcoding background operation, but need to load the three-dimensional graphics, through the SurfaceView to interact with the user gestures. How to deal with these UI interaction is a big problem, I hope you can give me some ideas, thank you

Comment: I don't think you can handle UI or perform live graphics through interprocess communication